# Area from 2d irregular polygon from 3d coordinates

Tags: 3d, geometry, polygon, area

I need to calculate the area of 2d irregular polygon surface, from its 3D coordinates.

I can compute the area of an irregular polygon from its 2d coordinates, but not from 3d coordinates.

I would like to do it in Excel or VBA, if possible.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: is it planar or curved or folded?  is the polygon linear or with curved edges? is it convex or concave? where exactly is the problem?  for planar polygon just create 2 perpendicular basis vectors `u,v` and origin point `p0` on the same plane as polygon and convert to 2D using dot product ...`pos2D.x = dot(pos3D-p0,u);  pos2D.y = dot(pos3D-p0,v); ` If you have triangulation you can compute the area directly in 3D by summing up the size of cross products of triangle edges / 2

Comment: The figure is planar but it is in 3D. It may be in a rotate plane (not in orthogonal axis plane). Your suggestion seems perfect. What you’re saying is that I could convert the 3D coordinates to a 2d coordinates and then compute the area? Could you please point out an example. Also, regarding 3D, you mean Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: any triangulation will do ... IIRC the area of 3D `triangle(p0,p1,p2)` is `0.5*length(cross(p1-p0,p2-p0))` ... for the 3D->2D you can take any 2 non parallel edges of your polygon(p0,p1,p2,p3,....) (`u=p1-p0; v=p2-p1; v=cross(u,v); v=cross(v,u);` and origin might be any of the polygon points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose any coordinate plane (Oxy, Oxz, Oyz) not perpendicular to your plane, calculate area of projection onto that plane - using 2D area algorithm like shoelace one and just ignoring the third coordinate.

At the end divide result by cosine of angle between your plane and used coordinate plane (might be found using dot product of your plane normal with corresponding axis).

This approach is rather effective because you don't need to calculate edge lengths